# Implement sql.Scanner interface on embedded pointers to primitive data types

Tags: sql, go

I would like to implement the interface

```
// Scanner is an interface used by Scan.
type Scanner interface {
    // Scan assigns a value from a database driver.
    //
    // The src value will be of one of the following types:
    //
    //    int64
    //    float64
    //    bool
    //    []byte
    //    string
    //    time.Time
    //    nil - for NULL values
    //
    // An error should be returned if the value cannot be stored
    // without loss of information.
    //
    // Reference types such as []byte are only valid until the next call to Scan
    // and should not be retained. Their underlying memory is owned by the driver.
    // If retention is necessary, copy their values before the next call to Scan.
    Scan(src any) error
}
```

on a struct like

```
type IntPtr struct {
    *int
}
```

How to do that safely? Do I need to switch on every possible src value type like

```
func (s *IntPtr) Scan(value interface{}) error {

    if value == nil {
        s.int = nil
        return nil
    }

    switch value.(type) {
    case int64:
        i := int(value.(int64))
        s.int = &i
    case float64:
        i := int(value.(float64))
        s.int = &i
    }

    return nil
}
```

I would like to achieve this for *string, *int, *bool and *time.Time.

Because it's only pointers to primitives, isn't there a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: „ isn't there a better solution?“ No.